# Are persistent cookies being used to log us into the sites?

Tags: support, login, cookies

If I close the browser and then opening it again and enter a Stack Exchange site, I am straightaway logged in.

Are persistent cookies being used to achieve that? If yes when is there a default time it will expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. There is an `acct` cookie that seems the authentication cookie to me, given its name and contents. It is set to expire in 6 months.